# Updating a list item from sharepoint online workflow using HttpSend

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-addin, rest

I'm trying to update a list item in the host web from a sharepoint app using workflow's `HttpSend` activity in visual studio.

How should I set the `RequestHeader` and `RequestContent` values ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this guys web page. http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2013/09/03/more-on-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-with-fiddler-and-spd/ it got me started. What I ened up doing was using his example to create REST Calls using the HttpSend activity.[image: Here you can see I get all the information I need to construct the Rest Call and do receive the responses]